# Show function definition in Ash and Dash

Tags: shell, function-definition, ash, dash-shell

In bash, you can use `type` to show the body of a function, as in

```
bash-4.3$ myfunc() { echo $@ ;}
bash-4.3$ type myfunc
myfunc is a function
myfunc () 
{ 
    echo $@
}
```

How can I display a shell function body in Ash and Dash?

Comment: The whole point of extensions is that they add capabilities that weren't otherwise available. If POSIX sh provided the facility, why would any extended shell bother to implement a different path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible in a POSIX shell such as dash.

Comment: The functions MUST be stored/remembered somewhere -- Where are they?

Comment: They're in the running process's memory.  That doesn't mean they're accessible within the shell.